# MacOs: How to select portion of screen and get CGRect (Position and coordinates) in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, screen-recording

I am trying to select a screen area/portion to record video of that portion but unfortunately, I haven't found any solution for that.

Here is my code to capture screenshot by selecting screen area,

```
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/sbin/screencapture"
        task.arguments = ["-i", "-r", destinationPath]
        task.launch()
        task.waitUntilExit()
```

It lets the user select an area and capture that area of the screen. Now I want the same to record video of the selected portion of the screen like in Quicktime screen recording. Have been searching around the way to select screen area but got no success.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: The code in this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48569738/2227743 (looks like it's for fullscreen though, but maybe you can modify it)

Comment: Thank you for your reply @EricAya but I'm looking for a solution to select the screen area.

Comment: Sure but you could probably add code to select the area. Or maybe have a look at `cropRect` as you can see in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturescreeninput

Comment: @EricAya `cropRect` needs coordinates and those will be obtained by selecting the screen area. Question is how to select the screen area?

Comment: @AdilMalik Were you ever able to find a solution to this? I'm struggling with the same issue.